# div контента от header до footer

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать каркас сайта.

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="wr-content">
    <div class="header">лого</div>
  <div id=1>Пошел текст</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Низ</div>
</body>
```

Сть шапка, основа, и футер. В div id 1 начинается основная часть страницы. Как растянуть этот div вниз до футера, и перед самим футером добавить еще один div, для вставки туда картинки.

вот css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #c0deed;
    color: #fff;
}
    #main{
        width: 80%;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -100px;
    }
    #footer{
        height: 100px;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        background-color: silver;
        padding-bottom: -100px;
    }
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь гуглом и посмотрите как это сделать. В конце концов найдите готовый пример и посмотрите ка он сделан.

Comment: Гляньте [по ссылке](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp) как сделаны шаблоны и ваш вопрос будет решен.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такие единицы измерения высоты - vh (viewport height). Вся высота экрана - это 100vh. Соответственно, Вы можете как угодно растягивать свои блоки по высоте, добавляя им нужно число vh:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#one {
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: green;
}
#footer {
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="wr-content">
      <div class="header">лого</div>
      <div id="one">Пошел текст</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Низ</div>
```

**P.S.** id=1 у Вас работать не будет, потому что имя идентификатора должно **обязательно** начинаться с латинской буквы: http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id Поменяйте на one или что-нибудь подобное.